# Ajax long polling not working correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery, long-integer, long-polling

I am developing a simple strangers  chat application using long polling in MVC 2. Its works fine in my development machine if i am opening the application different browsers.. i mean if i loaded the application in  IE and mozilla, it works fine

if i took the appliction in two tabs of a browser (eg:IE) , the long polling are not firing from both tabs.. I mean, there is a start button to start chat which fire long polling. I can see it calling actions while debugging.. And my problem is, When i clicked start button from tab one , it fire a ajax request (long polling ( this req wait at server till another reqst comes)).and then i click the start button in tab two, it does not fire the ajax request until the first request is returned from the server(after timeout).

why this is happening? I read like browser will block multiple ajax request..Is that a reason for that? ..It work fine if i am using different browsers.The problem only came if i took two tab in same browser

Comment: Just a guess, but have you made sure that the response is never cached with `Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)` ? I would recommend using [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com) to debug if the request is being made at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I read like browser will block multiple ajax request.

Yes, if you use sessions, ASP.NET blocks concurrent requests from the same session. Quote from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx):

> Access to ASP.NET session state is
>   exclusive per session, which means
>   that if two different users make
>   concurrent requests, access to each
>   separate session is granted
>   concurrently. However, if two
>   concurrent requests are made for the
>   same session (by using the same
>   SessionID value), the first request
>   gets exclusive access to the session
>   information. The second request
>   executes only after the first request
>   is finished. (The second session can
>   also get access if the exclusive lock
>   on the information is freed because
>   the first request exceeds the lock
>   time-out.) If the EnableSessionState
>   value in the @ Page directive is set
>   to ReadOnly, a request for the
>   read-only session information does not
>   result in an exclusive lock on the
>   session data. However, read-only
>   requests for session data might still
>   have to wait for a lock set by a
>   read-write request for session data to
>   clear.

Also make sure that you have disabled caching. For example if you use jquery use the `cache: false` option when polling:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/poll',
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {
        // ...
    }
});
```